# Who is the captain of the Lord's Host spoken of in Joshua 5:13-15?

Tags: joshua

> Joshua 5:13-15 And it came to pass, when Joshua was by Jericho, that he lifted up his eyes and looked, and, behold, there stood a man over against him with his sword drawn in his hand: and Joshua went unto him, and said unto him, Art thou for us, or for our adversaries? And he said, Nay; but as ***captain of the host of the LORD*** am I now come. And Joshua fell on his face to the earth, and ***did worship***, and said unto him, What saith my lord unto his servant? ***And the captain of the LORD'S host said unto Joshua, Loose thy shoe from off thy foot; for the place whereon thou standest is holy. And Joshua did so.***

My question is who is the captain of the Lord's Host?

Comment: Short answer, yes it most likely is God himself

Comment: Why hast thou created different sites? Just join everything we are one big family.

Comment: @SSumner Technically things across different SE sites are [not duplicates](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1651/30). I've dropped your comment in favor of one that does't cause confusion about what qualifies as a "duplicate" since that is terminology we use when closing questions here.

Comment: @TonyJays: The [hermeneutics.se] site is part of the same network of QnA sites, and were are lots of crossover users, but the scope of the site is rather different than here. Over there, Jewish as well as Christian exegetical work is in scope and questions do not have to be directed at specific doctrinal traditions. Instead they must be rooted in a specific textual issue. Some questions could be asked either place, but the kind of answer you'll get is rather different. Do you want to know how the text was originally understood or whether Christians have any doctrine related to this text?

Comment: @Caleb - oops. I just asked a very similar meta question to that one.

Comment: The Jewish original please...

Comment: @Tony Jewish original interpretations are definetly off topic for Christianity.SE. I have migrated your question to the site where that would be on topic and marked it of a duplicate of the question that already asks about that issue. If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask again about whatever issue isn't covered by the original question, and if you have something specific about Christian doctrine feel free to ask back over there.

Comment: I just wrote an answer at the location of the original question...